# Magetno 2 custom module how to Update DB Table row with model

Tags: upgrade, model, magento2.2.2, save

How do I update instead of inserting new row on save using model

My code:

```
$question = $this->_objectManager->create('Vendor\HelloWorld\Model\Question');
$question->setTitle('Simple Question');
$question->setDescription('Question Description');
$question->setQuestion('I have an Updated question');
$question->save();
```

If a user already exist this way it isn't updating is creating new row 
with the same user `user_id`.

How do one update the row using model example above?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code for updating and creating new rows:

```
$question = $this->_objectManager->create('Vendor\HelloWorld\Model\Question');
if($question_id){
    $question->load($question_id);
}
$data = array('title' => 'Simple Question', 'description' => 'Question Description', 'question' => 'I have an Updated question');
$question->setData($data);
$question->save();
```

If question id is there that means you are going to update and if not then you are creating new record.

Comment: I've tried that already But I've found a way that works but not sure       Why using methods isn't updating the way ended up working is  your suggestion and `$question->load($question_id);`  and using `setData()` `$question->setData('title', 'Simple Question''); $question->setData('desccription', 'Question Description''); $question->setData('question', 'I have an Updated question''); `

Comment: You can also create a array with key-value pair and update it by setData(array)->save(). This will also works.

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: I tested It and didn't work as an Array `$data = array('title' => 'Simple Question', 'description' => 'Question Description', 'question' => 'I have an Updated question');
$question->setData($data);` not sure why really strange. But up voted  put me in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks. Did you add save() at the end?